# Unable to Identify presently the Checked/Selected radio button in a list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a webpage with some question and options to select for the question in the form of radio button.
As shown below:

[image]

I can only select one radio button at a time.
However I can change my selection at any point of time.

I want to identify the presently the Checked/Selected radio button in a list.

Below is the html code of source page before making any selection

```html
<div class="ec-question-radios ng-scope">
<!-- ngRepeat: option in settings.get('options') -->
<div class="ec-question-radios__radio ng-scope" data-ng-click="setValue(option.id)" data-ng-repeat="option in settings.get('options')" role="button" tabindex="0">
<label class="ec-question-radios__label">
<input id="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question21" class="ec-question-radios__input ng-pristine **ng-untouched** ng-valid ng-empty" type="radio" value="1" data-ng-model="$parent.ngModel" name="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question21" aria-invalid="false"/>
<span class="ec-question-radios__text ng-binding">                         It wouldn't have an impact on my standard of living and I wouldn't need to use any additional resources (for example, savings) as a result.                     </span>
</label>
</div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: option in settings.get('options') -->
<div class="ec-question-radios__radio ng-scope" data-ng-click="setValue(option.id)" data-ng-repeat="option in settings.get('options')" role="button" tabindex="0">
<label class="ec-question-radios__label">
<input id="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question22" class="ec-question-radios__input ng-pristine **ng-untouched** ng-valid ng-empty" type="radio" value="2" data-ng-model="$parent.ngModel" name="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question22" aria-invalid="false"/>
<span class="ec-question-radios__text ng-binding">                         I have other resources I could fall back on.                     </span>
</label>
</div>
```

I had found one solution too that after making any selection, the **ng-untouched** class name in input tab changes to **ng-touched**.
However when I change my selection from option 1 to option 2 or 3 or any from list, the class name in option one remains **ng-touched**. and suppose I changed my selection from option 1 to 2 the class name of input tag changes to **ng-touched**.

As shown in below html snippet.

```html
<div class="ec-question-radios__radio ng-scope" data-ng-click="setValue(option.id)" data-ng-repeat="option in settings.get('options')" role="button" tabindex="0">
<label class="ec-question-radios__label">
<input id="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question21" class="ec-question-radios__input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" type="radio" value="1" data-ng-model="$parent.ngModel" name="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question21" aria-invalid="false"/>
<span class="ec-question-radios__text ng-binding">                         It wouldn't have an impact on my standard of living and I wouldn't need to use any additional resources (for example, savings) as a result.                     </span>
</label>
</div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: option in settings.get('options') -->
<div class="ec-question-radios__radio ng-scope" data-ng-click="setValue(option.id)" data-ng-repeat="option in settings.get('options')" role="button" tabindex="0">
<label class="ec-question-radios__label">
<input id="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question22" class="ec-question-radios__input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" type="radio" value="2" data-ng-model="$parent.ngModel" name="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question22" aria-invalid="false"/>
<span class="ec-question-radios__text ng-binding">                         I have other resources I could fall back on.                     </span>
</label>
</div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: option in settings.get('options') -->
<div class="ec-question-radios__radio ng-scope" data-ng-click="setValue(option.id)" data-ng-repeat="option in settings.get('options')" role="button" tabindex="0">
<label class="ec-question-radios__label">
<input id="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question23" class="ec-question-radios__input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" type="radio" value="3" data-ng-model="$parent.ngModel" name="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question23" aria-invalid="false"/>
<span class="ec-question-radios__text ng-binding">                         It would have an impact on my immediate standard of living.                     </span>
</label>
</div>
```

I am not getting any unique way by which I can identify the presently selected radio button.
Can anyone pleas help me out here?

Comment: Found solution using JavaScript. Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `isSelected` which returns `True` if input (check-box/radio-button) is currently selected/checked.

I'm not sure that this code is totally correct as I'm not `Java` coder, but it might looks like:

```
for(int i=0; i<=3; i++)
    {
    if ( driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question')]")).get(i).isSelected() )
        {
         WebElement selected_element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question')]")).get(i);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already tried with isSelected(), however it is not returning me true anytime. even when one of the option/radio button is selected while iterating through the list of available answers for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Better if you can use common attribute id or class for all the radio button. Then first get the list of all the radio button then it can be check which one is selected or deselected
Lets suppose your all radio button have common id = question

```
List<WebElement> allRadiobtn = driver.findElements(By.id("question"));
int iSize = allRadiobtn.size();
boolean bValue = false;
for(int i=0; i < iSize ; i++ ){
   bValue = allRadiobtn.get(i).isSelected();
   if(bValue == true){
           // do some action
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already tried with isSelected(), however it is not returning me true anytime. even when one of the option/radio button is selected while iterating through the list of available answers for the question.

Comment: @PriyaP can you check that are you able to click on the option by allRadiobtn.get(i).click() or try with xpath.  if still not able to find the option then have to try something else

Comment: It is allowing me to click/select the radio button, but not getting any way to return the selected radio button from the list, when I want to cross verify it.
What I am trying to do is.. 
I am selection one option, moving to other page, coming back to the previous page where I selected the radio button option and validating that the one I selected, still selected or not.

Comment: ok. Now I think have to check that any hidden value set for the radio button or not. Can you check it in firebug

Comment: Yea, Tried many ways, even tried to identify any change in CSS property of radio button. But no success yet.
Also isSelected and isChecked is not working in my case.

Comment: I see you have too add ng-untouched class on clicked check box and remove ng-untouched on other 2 check boxes. with this you can get the checked radio button. Please try blow change in html code

Comment: Yes, but none applied in my case.
So I did it using javascript fetching the color of the selected radio button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  function add_class(value_check){
  if(value_check == "1"){
    var d = document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question21");
    d.classList.add("ng-untouched");
    document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question22").classList.remove("ng-untouched");
    document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question23").classList.remove("ng-untouched");
    }
    else if(value_check == "2"){
    var d1 = document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question22");
    d1.classList.add("ng-untouched");
    document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question21").classList.remove("ng-untouched");
    document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question23").classList.remove("ng-untouched");
    }
    else if(value_check == "3"){
    var d2 = document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question23");
    d2.classList.add("ng-untouched");
    document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question21").classList.remove("ng-untouched");
    document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question22").classList.remove("ng-untouched");
    }
  }
 </script>
```

```html
<div class="ec-question-radios__radio ng-scope" data-ng-click="setValue(option.id)" data-ng-repeat="option in settings.get('options')" role="button" tabindex="0">
<label class="ec-question-radios__label">
<input id="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question21" class="ec-question-radios__input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" type="radio" value="1" data-ng-model="$parent.ngModel" name="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question" aria-invalid="false" onclick="add_class('1');"/>
<span class="ec-question-radios__text ng-binding">                         It wouldn't have an impact on my standard of living and I wouldn't need to use any additional resources (for example, savings) as a result.                     </span>
</label>
</div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: option in settings.get('options') -->
<div class="ec-question-radios__radio ng-scope" data-ng-click="setValue(option.id)" data-ng-repeat="option in settings.get('options')" role="button" tabindex="0">
<label class="ec-question-radios__label">
<input id="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question22" class="ec-question-radios__input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" type="radio" value="2" data-ng-model="$parent.ngModel" name="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question" aria-invalid="false"  onclick="add_class('2');"/>
<span class="ec-question-radios__text ng-binding">                         I have other resources I could fall back on.                     </span>
</label>
</div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: option in settings.get('options') -->
<div class="ec-question-radios__radio ng-scope" data-ng-click="setValue(option.id)" data-ng-repeat="option in settings.get('options')" role="button" tabindex="0">
<label class="ec-question-radios__label">
<input id="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question23" class="ec-question-radios__input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" type="radio" value="3" data-ng-model="$parent.ngModel" name="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question" aria-invalid="false" onclick="add_class('3');"/>
<span class="ec-question-radios__text ng-binding">                         It would have an impact on my immediate standard of living.                     </span>
</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
      function add_class(value_check){
      if(value_check == "1"){
        var d = document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question21");
        d.classList.add("ng-untouched");
        document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question22").classList.remove("ng-untouched");
        document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question23").classList.remove("ng-untouched");
        }
        else if(value_check == "2"){
        var d1 = document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question22");
        d1.classList.add("ng-untouched");
        document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question21").classList.remove("ng-untouched");
        document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question23").classList.remove("ng-untouched");
        }
        else if(value_check == "3"){
        var d2 = document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question23");
        d2.classList.add("ng-untouched");
        document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question21").classList.remove("ng-untouched");
        document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question22").classList.remove("ng-untouched");
        }
      }
     </script>
```

```js
function add_class(value_check){
  if(value_check == "1"){
 var d = document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question21");
 d.classList.add("ng-untouched");
 document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question22").classList.remove("ng-untouched");
 document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question23").classList.remove("ng-untouched");
 }
 else if(value_check == "2"){
 var d1 = document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question22");
 d1.classList.add("ng-untouched");
 document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question21").classList.remove("ng-untouched");
 document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question23").classList.remove("ng-untouched");
 }
 else if(value_check == "3"){
 var d2 = document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question23");
 d2.classList.add("ng-untouched");
 document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question21").classList.remove("ng-untouched");
 document.getElementById("ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question22").classList.remove("ng-untouched");
 }
  }
```

```html
<div class="ec-question-radios__radio ng-scope" data-ng-click="setValue(option.id)" data-ng-repeat="option in settings.get('options')" role="button" tabindex="0">
    <label class="ec-question-radios__label">
    <input id="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question21" class="ec-question-radios__input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" type="radio" value="1" data-ng-model="$parent.ngModel" name="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question" aria-invalid="false" onclick="add_class('1');"/>
    <span class="ec-question-radios__text ng-binding">                         It wouldn't have an impact on my standard of living and I wouldn't need to use any additional resources (for example, savings) as a result.                     </span>
    </label>
    </div>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: option in settings.get('options') -->
    <div class="ec-question-radios__radio ng-scope" data-ng-click="setValue(option.id)" data-ng-repeat="option in settings.get('options')" role="button" tabindex="0">
    <label class="ec-question-radios__label">
    <input id="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question22" class="ec-question-radios__input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" type="radio" value="2" data-ng-model="$parent.ngModel" name="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question" aria-invalid="false"  onclick="add_class('2');"/>
    <span class="ec-question-radios__text ng-binding">                         I have other resources I could fall back on.                     </span>
    </label>
    </div>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: option in settings.get('options') -->
    <div class="ec-question-radios__radio ng-scope" data-ng-click="setValue(option.id)" data-ng-repeat="option in settings.get('options')" role="button" tabindex="0">
    <label class="ec-question-radios__label">
    <input id="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question23" class="ec-question-radios__input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" type="radio" value="3" data-ng-model="$parent.ngModel" name="ec-portfolio-planner-default-questionnaire-question" aria-invalid="false" onclick="add_class('3');"/>
    <span class="ec-question-radios__text ng-binding">                         It would have an impact on my immediate standard of living.                     </span>
    </label>
    </div>
```